# Salesforce URL hack to edit & save in one button

Tags: visualforce, custom-button

We use to have a button with URL hack to edit a record and save it. But it stopped working on Spring 14 release. Any idea how to make it work again?

Here is our current URL. To be specific, save=x is our problem. Without it, the edit works and we will have to do the save explicitly again.

```
/{!Opp.Id}/e?retURL=%2F{!Opp.Id}&opp11=Contract+Complete&opp12=91&save=x
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Mm?! 'The page you submitted was invalid for your session. Please click Save again to confirm your change.' Interesting yeah it doesn't work anymore

Comment: I thinks its high time to ditch this approach and start looking at ajax route to attain the same functionality.

Comment: I am with you; but still I cannot deny the fact that this looks totally cool. Very simple yet powerful!

Answer (score 3):

Haha, I think I found [your answer](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176169&language=en_US)

> **Resolution**
>
> NOTE: This is considered a URL hack and it is not supported by
>   Salesforce. Using undocumented query strings is absolutely discouraged
>   as Salesforce can change them at any time without notice. Instead this
>   requirement can be implemented by using the Force.com AJAX toolkit or
>   a Visualforce page with a custom controller.
>
> Salesforce has implemented several features to prevent Cross-Site
>   Request Forgery (CSRF). As an example when a browser makes a request a
>   one-time token is attached to prevent CSRF attacks, however this also
>   prevents the use of the mentioned URL as clicking on it would generate
>   a GET request without the CSRF token.
>
> Salesforce Support can disable the validation of the token on GET
>   requests, but this opens up the Salesforce application to CSRF
>   attacks. We strongly recommend that this feature remain enabled.
>   Customers can request this feature to be disabled though by raising a
>   case that contains the following statement/request:
>
> "Please disable the validation of the CSRF token on GET requests. I
>   acknowledge I understand that my organisation may be potentially
>   exposed to CSRF attacks, and I will continue without the feature at my
>   own risk."