# URL hack - create & save record without viewing edit screen

Tags: urlhacking

I'm looking for a way to use URL hacking to create a child record from a parent object's record, without leaving the parent object record's page.

I have the following URL for my custom detail page button, which has been created on the parent object.

```
/a5H/e?CF00N70000003TE86={!MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Task__c.Name}
&00N70000003TEAJ={!MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Task__c.Time_To_Record__c}
&00N70000003TEAH={!TODAY()}
&retURL=/{!MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Task__c.Id}
```

Which works fine but obviously when this is clicked, I am taken to the edit page for the new record.

I have seen [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29469/salesforce-url-hack-to-edit-save-in-one-button) which suggests that this functionality's not possible but I've also seen [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/11338/10720) which seems to suggest that it might be.

When I try to adapt the solution from the answer on post 2, using an encoded URL (adding `&save=1` to the end of the above url)

```
/a5H/e?CF00N70000003TE86%3D%7B!MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Task__c.Name%7D%0A%2600N70000003TEAJ%3D%7B!MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Task__c.Time_To_Record__c%7D%0A%2600N70000003TEAH%3D%7B!TODAY()%7D%0A%26retURL%3D%7B!MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Task__c.Id%7D%0A%26save%3D1
```

I'm just taken to the edit page of the child record and none of the fields are prepopulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex,

You can do this in a Flow pretty easily.  I almost think the URL hack might be more confusing than a simple Flow triggered by the button.

Button Pressed -->  Pass record ID into the Flow --> Create the child record with a Record Create --> Return to Parent Record w/ RetURL or VFP return on the Parent Record.

If you need to reference more fields, you can do some lookups or pass some in via the VFP or URL.

Comment: Thanks David, that's 'admin friendly' so it works for me. Your answer prompted me to consider the Process Builder & I realized that I could create the new record whenever the Time To Record field on the parent was populated / changed - but I was asking about a button in the question & that's what your solution would enable me to use.

Answer (score 0):

believe in option 1 you miss the / before the record id in returl param

```
/a5H/e?CF00N70000003TE86={!MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Task__c.Name}&00N70000003TEAJ={!MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Task__c.Time_To_Record__c}&00N70000003TEAH={!TODAY()}&retURL=/{!MPM4_BASE__Milestone1_Task__c.Id}
```

instead of url hack , I suggest you try to use publisher action or custom javascript button options ..

Comment: Thanks Vamsi, thought I'd ask the question to see whether this is possible with a URL hack, despite the other options - hacks are easier for an admin to adopt. I'll add the / to the return URL, to keep the Q&A focused on the main question.